# How to redirect `system` call when passing options as separate arguments?

Tags: ruby, io-redirection

Rails 6.1.4.1
Brakeman 5.1.1

I'm updating a legacy rails project that has the following command:

```
    system("pg_dump -F c --no-acl --no-owner --quote-all-identifiers #{database_url} > #{file_name}")
```

Brakeman is complaining of command injection.
One solution I found online would be to split the command into separate strings:

```
system('pg_dump', '-F', 'c', '--no-acl', '--no-owner', '--quote-all-identifiers', database_url, '>', file_name)
```

However now it seems it thinks that `database_url > file_name` is part of the arguments passed to pgdump, and won't dump to `file_name`

How can I easily fix this line?

Thanks!

Comment: You could switch to Open3 and handle the file IO yourself instead of using the shell's redirection.

Comment: @akira : Alternatively (if you don't want to use Open3), you could - instead of using output redirection - catch the output into a Ruby variable and then write the content of the variable to a file. This assumes that the expected output is not so large that you will run out of memory.

Comment: @akira : Another idea. My guess is (you have to verify this), that brakeman checks `tainted?` and/or `untrusted?` on the interpolated string for issuing this warning. If this is the case, you can manually check that the string is safe, and then `untaint` or `trust` it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance at the docs for [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#system-method) reveals that:

> The hash arguments, env and options, are same as `exec` and `spawn`. See [`#spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) for details.

Among the many options for [`spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) there's *redirection* via `key => value`. The key for stdout is `:out` and the value can be a string to specify a file name:

```
system('pg_dump', '-F', 'c', '...', database_url, out: file_name)
```